# Catalan identity to calculate the determinant of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant, combinatorial-proofs, catalan-numbers

I want to show that the determinant of the matrix $A$ of order $n\times n$ with entries $a_{ij}=C_{i+j-2}$ is $1$, where $C_m$ is the $m$th term of the Catalan sequence. To solve this problem, the hint is defining a decomposition $LU$ of $A$.

> Set $\,u_{ij}\,$ to be
> $$ u_{ij} = \frac{2i+1}{i+j+1}{2j \choose j-i}, $$
> and let $\,U_n = (u_{ij})_{0\le i,j\le n-1},\,$ which is an
> $\,n\times n\,$ upper triangle matrix whose diagonal entries
> are $\,1.\,$ Put $\,L_n = \,^{t}U_{n}.\,$ Then we can show
> that $\,C_n^0 = L_nU_n,\,$ which immediately implies that
> $\,\det C_n^0 = 1.\,$ We omit the detail but one can easily
> prove that these $\,LU$-decompositions reduce to the
> following identity:
> $$ \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(2k+1)^2}{(i+k+1)(j+k+1)}
>    {2i \choose i-k}{2j \choose j-k} = \frac1{i+j+1}
>    {2i+2j \choose i+j}. $$

My question is regarding the U matrix, I don't know why it is triangular, but in case such how can I prove the mentioned identity?

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcDM3.png

Comment: Notice that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k<0.$

Comment: A matrix $U$ is upper triangular iff $U_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$. By definition, binomial products are usually defined as $\binom{m}{k}=0$ for $k<0$ or $k>m$.

Comment: Related: https://cdm.ucalgary.ca/article/view/62631/53779

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

The identity

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(2k+1)^2}{(p+k+1)(q+k+1)}
{2p\choose p-k} {2q\choose q-k} =
\frac{1}{p+q+1} {2p+2q\choose p+q}$$

is identical to

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\min(p,q)} (2k+1)^2
{2p+1\choose p+k+1} {2q+1\choose q+k+1} =
\frac{(2p+1)(2q+1)}{p+q+1} {2p+2q\choose p+q}$$

or

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\min(p,q)} (2k+1)^2
{2p+1\choose p-k} {2q+1\choose q-k} =
\frac{(2p+1)(2q+1)}{p+q+1} {2p+2q\choose p+q}.$$

The LHS is

$$S= [z^p] (1+z)^{2p+1} [w^q] (1+w)^{2q+1}
\sum_{k=0}^{\min(p,q)} (2k+1)^2 z^k w^k.$$

The two coefficient extractors enforce the upper limit of the sum:

$$[z^p] (1+z)^{2p+1} [w^q] (1+w)^{2q+1}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (2k+1)^2 z^k w^k
\\ = [z^p] (1+z)^{2p+1} [w^q] (1+w)^{2q+1}
\frac{z^2 w^2 + 6 z w + 1}{(1-zw)^3}
\\ = - [z^p] \frac{1}{z^3} (1+z)^{2p+1} [w^q] (1+w)^{2q+1}
\frac{z^2 w^2 + 6 z w + 1}{(w-1/z)^3}
\\ = - [z^{p+3}] (1+z)^{2p+1} [w^q] (1+w)^{2q+1}
\frac{z^2 w^2 + 6 z w + 1}{(w-1/z)^3}.$$

The coefficient extractor in $w$ is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^{q+1}} (1+w)^{2q+1}
\frac{z^2 w^2 + 6 z w + 1}{(w-1/z)^3}.$$

#### Residue at infinity

Now residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is given by

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2}
w^{q+1} \frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{2q+1}} 
\frac{z^2/w^2 + 6 z/w + 1}{(1/w-1/z)^3}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+2}} 
\frac{z^2 w + 6 z w^2 + w^3}{(1-w/z)^3}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+1}} 
\frac{z^2 + 6 z w + w^2}{(1-w/z)^3}.$$

Next applying the coefficient extractor in $z$ we find

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2p+1}}{z^{p+4}}  \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+1}} 
\frac{z^2 + 6 z w + w^2}{(1-w/z)^3}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2p+1}}{z^{p+2}}  \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+1}} 
\frac{1 + 6 w/z + w^2/z^2}{(1-w/z)^3}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2p+1}}{z^{p+2}}  \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+1}} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} (2k+1)^2 \frac{w^k}{z^k}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} (2k+1)^2 
{2p+1\choose p+k+1} {2q+1\choose q-k} = S.$$

This means that $S$ is minus  half the residue at $w=1/z$, substituted
into the coefficient extractor in $z.$

#### Residue at $w=1/z$

The residue at $w=1/z$ is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=1/z} \frac{1}{w^{q+1}} (1+w)^{2q+1}
\frac{z^2 w^2 + 6 z w + 1}{(w-1/z)^3}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{w=1/z} \frac{1}{w^{q+1}} (1+w)^{2q+1}
\left(\frac{8}{(w-1/z)^3} + \frac{8z}{(w-1/z)^2} + 
\frac{z^2}{w-1/z}\right).$$

Evaluating the three pieces in turn we start with

$$8\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ (1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+1}}\right)''
= 4 (q+1)(q+2)\frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+3}}
\\ - 8(q+1)(2q+1)\frac{(1+w)^{2q}}{w^{q+2}}
+ 4 (2q+1)(2q)\frac{(1+w)^{2q-1}}{w^{q+1}}.$$

Evaluate at $w=1/z$ to get

$$4(q+1)(q+2) \frac{(1+z)^{2q+1}}{z^{q-2}}
\\ - 8 (q+1)(2q+1) \frac{(1+z)^{2q}}{z^{q-2}} 
+ 4 (2q+1)(2q) \frac{(1+z)^{2q-1}}{z^{q-2}}.$$

Substituting into the coefficient extractor in $z$ we find

$$- 4(q+1)(q+2) {2p+2q+2\choose p+q+1}
\\ + 8 (q+1)(2q+1) {2p+2q+1\choose p+q+1}
- 4 (2q+1)(2q) {2p+2q\choose p+q+1}.$$

Continuing with the middle piece we have

$$8z\left(\frac{ (1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+1}}\right)'
= -8z (q+1) \frac{(1+w)^{2q+1}}{w^{q+2}}
+8z (2q+1) \frac{(1+w)^{2q}}{w^{q+1}}.$$

Evaluate at $w=1/z$ to get

$$-8(q+1) \frac{(1+z)^{2q+1}}{z^{q-2}} 
+ 8(2q+1) \frac{(1+z)^{2q}}{z^{q-2}}.$$

The coefficient extractor now yields

$$8(q+1) {2p+2q+2\choose p+q+1} - 8(2q+1) {2p+2q+1\choose p+q+1}.$$

The third and last piece produces

$$\frac{(1+z)^{2q+1}}{z^{q-2}}$$

which when substituted into the coefficient extractor yields

$$-{2p+2q+2\choose p+q+1}.$$

#### Collecting the three pieces

We get

$$-(2q+1)^2 {2p+2q+2\choose p+q+1}
+ 8q (2q+1) {2p+2q+1\choose p+q+1}
- 8q (2q+1) {2p+2q\choose p+q+1}
\\ = -(2q+1)^2 {2p+2q+2\choose p+q+1}
+ 8q (2q+1) {2p+2q\choose p+q}
\\ = - 2 (2q+1)^2 {2p+2q+1\choose p+q}
+ 8q (2q+1) {2p+2q\choose p+q}
\\ = - 2 (2q+1)^2 \frac{2p+2q+1}{p+q+1} {2p+2q\choose p+q}
+ 8q (2q+1) {2p+2q\choose p+q}
\\ = -2 \frac{(2p+1)(2q+1)}{p+q+1} {2p+2q\choose p+q}.$$

Halve this value and flip the sign to obtain the coveted

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{(2p+1)(2q+1)}{p+q+1} {2p+2q\choose p+q}.}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, a bit of a background. In the Cartesian plane, consider walks in which each step is either one unit to the right or one unit up.  A walk with $2n$ steps (for some $n\in\mathbb N$) from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ is said to follow a ***Dyck path*** (after German **Walther von Dyck**) if it does not venture below the line $y=x$.  More generally, we can say that a walk with $2n$ steps from $(0,0)$ to $(n+k,n-k)$ (for some $0\le k\le n$) follows a ***generalized Dyck path with parameters*** $(n,k)$ if it does not venture below $y=x$.

**Lemma.** *The number of generalized Dyck paths with parameters $(n,k)$ is*
$$
\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\,\binom{2n}{n-k}.$$
**Proof.** The total number of walks with $2n$ steps from $(0,0)$ to $(n+k,n-k)$ is $\binom{2n}{n-k}$.  Of these, the walks that do not follow a generalized Dyck path, at some point reach line $\ell:=\{(x,y)\mid y=x-1\}$.  There is a natural bijection between the latter walks and the walks with $2n$ steps from $(1,-1)$ to $(n+k,n-k)$: to toggle between the two types of walks, reflect in $\ell$ the portion of the walk from its start till it reaches $\ell$ for the first time, keeping the rest of the walk intact.  As there are $\binom{2n}{n-k-1}$ walks with $2n$ steps from $(1,-1)$ to $(n+k,n-k)$, the number of generalized Dyck paths with parameters $(n,k)$ is
$$
\binom{2n}{n-k}-\binom{2n}{n-k-1}
=\left(1-\frac{n-k}{n+k+1}\right)\,\binom{2n}{n-k}=
\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\,\binom{2n}{n-k}.
$$
$\square$

Now, onto your question. Setting $n:=i+j$, the RHS of the identity is
$$
    \frac{1}{n+1}\,\binom{2n}{n},\qquad\text{(called ${C_n}$, the $n^{t\hspace{-0.1mm}h}$ Catalan number)}
$$
which counts the number of "ordinary" (i.e., $k=0$) Dyck paths with $2n$ steps.  This number can also be obtained as follows.  For all $k\in\{0,1,\dots,\min(i,j)\}$, count the number of Dyck paths with $2n$ steps and exactly $i+k$ steps up among the first $2i$ steps (and, therefore, with exactly $j+k$ steps to the right among the last $2j$ steps); then add up the results.  This is precisely what the LHS does.